# Salvar multiplos dados do textarea PHP E PDO

Tags: php, html, pdo

Bom dia,

Tenho o seguinte script que preciso que salva todos os dados do textarea linha por linha porem o script salva apenas a primeira linha e ignora o resto

recebo os dados assim no textarea

```
0001:0001:0001:0001
0001:0001:0001:0001
0001:0001:0001:0001
```

meu codigo

```
    <?php


if (isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'cadastrar'):

    $lista = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lista'));
    list($a, $b, $c, $d) = explode(":", $lista);
    $valor = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'valor'));
    $data = '21-05-2015';


    $verificar_adm = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT id FROM `infocc` WHERE cc = ?");
    $verificar_adm->execute(array($user));

    if (!$val->validar()) {

        $erros = $val->getErro();
        echo '<div class="erros">Erro: ' . $erros[0] . '</div>';
    } elseif ($verificar_adm->rowCount() > 0) {

        echo '<br><br> <span align="center" class="help-block note"><i class="icon-warning-sign"></i> Duplicado.</span>';
    } else {

        $dados_cadastrar = array(
            'n' => $n,
            'a' => $a,
            'b' => $b,
            'c' => $c,
            'd' => $d,
            'v' => $v,
            'f' => 'N'
        );

        if ($site->inserir('tabela', $dados_cadastrar)) {

            echo '<br><br> <span align="center" class="help-block note"><i class="icon-warning-sign"></i> Ok</span>';
        } else {

            echo '<br><br> <span align="center" class="help-block note"><i class="icon-warning-sign"></i> Erro Grave, tente novamente.</span>';
        }
    }
endif;
?>
```

o que devo fazer para salvar todos os registro ?

Comment: Se isto for algum _framework_, e parece que é mesmo, as pessoas não vão saber como ajudar, porque não descreveste nem colocaste no código algumas das funções.

Comment: Coloca o código de `inserir()`